# After installing ubuntu 12.04.2, I can't load windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, boot-repair

I have a laptop with in-built windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 64 bit via the method shown on this Ubuntu page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

After use *boot-repair*, in GRUB menu it shows Windows 8 as well. But on clicking it, it shows errors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you show the errors?

Comment: What is the URL provided by the Recommended Repair of Boot-Repair ?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem when I installed Ubuntu 64 bit (12.10) and you also like me messed up the Windows 8 boot partition. So now your only options are:

- Re-install winidows 8
- Fix the windows 8 boot

See also:

- http://www.techspot.com/guides/630-windows-8-boot-fix/
- http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record/

Answer (score 0):

Reporting the precise errors you're seeing might be a helpful diagnostic. Chances are, though, that you haven't broken your Windows; it's probably just a GRUB problem. Some ideas for getting it working:

- Install [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Installing the Debian package should set it up properly; however, you might need to do the next thing, too.
- Disable Secure Boot. Details of how to do this vary from one system to another, but as a general rule, you'll need to enter your firmware's setup utility and look for an option labeled "Secure Boot" to disable it.
- Create a custom boot entry for Windows, via an entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, as shown below. Details will vary depending on where your EFI System Partition (ESP) is, though. After you create this entry, you'll need to type `sudo update-grub` to update GRUB's runtime configuration file.

The sample `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` entry is:

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Note that `(hd0,gpt1)` must point to your ESP, so it may need to be changed to match your partitioning layout.